# Regex matching interpretation with whitespace/non-digit/word boundary

Tags: java, regex, string

We have the following code

```
String str = "ABC 2015 ABC1";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+\\D\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(">" + matcher.group() + "<");
}
```

Our assumption is that it should match ABC and 2015 with the word boundaries around (which are not consuming chars), w+ word chars matching for the substrings themselves, and then non-digit \D for the whitespace. ABC1 should not match because there is no whitespace following

The result printout

```
>ABC <
>2015 <
```

seems to confirm this, however altering str slightly starts to raise doubts whether the above matching interpretation is correct. E.g.

- modifying it to "ABC 2015 ABC1 " with trailing whitespace seems to produce the very same result, with no match for >ABC1 <
- modifying it to "ABC" with no trailing whitespace produces >ABC< seeming to indicate that the \D might now matching for 'C' thus w+ not greedily consuming all the alphabetic chars
- modifying it to "ABC " with trailing whitespace produces >ABC< again, confusing the situation further

It would be appreciated if someone could explain what should be the correct interpretation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and then non-digit \D for the whitespace.

But there isn't a word boundary exists between white-space and the next character.

Your regex must be,

```
"\\b\\w+(?=\\s)"
```

Comment: Thank you but the question was how to interpret the above matching, not how to modify it

Comment: you mean this `"\\b\\w+(?=\\D)"`

Answer (score 1):

I think that your confusion stems from misunderstanding `\b` - word-boundary.

`\b` is a *zero-length* match, and it will match any beginning or end of a word `\w+`.

In our case, the string `"ABC 2015 ABC1"` obviously won't match due to the `\D`.

By adding white-spaces, you create a good match for the following part of the regex `\\b\\w+\\D` --> `"ABC1 "` but now the word boundary won't match because after the space there isn't any start/end of a word.

If you'll modify the string to:  `"ABC 2015 ABC1 x"` it will "fix" the issue because the additional new character will provide a match due to the (zero-length) word-boundary that comes before it.

Avinash wrote a correct answer that also explains the issue - but you didn't understand it (read again the first two lines of his answer) and I think that his answer should be accepted (+1 from me).

Comment: With that said, what I still don't see is that why the match groups end with space, e.g. >ABC <? This would indicate that the last real consumed char for this match, i.e. the \D, should be the space, but then what is the closing word boundary?

Comment: @hammerfest indeed, `\D` which stands for any non-digit character matches the space. The word-boundary that follows `"ABC "` is due to the "2015" that follows it: "2015" is another "word" and the zero-length boundary that comes before it matches the `\b` that comes after `\\b\\w+\\D`

Comment: Thank you. But doesn't this contradict with Avinash' answer above "But there isn't a word boundary exists between white-space and the next character" which you have referred as correct?

Comment: @hammerfest and what is that "next character" ? in case of `""ABC 2015 ABC1 "` there is no such character, the next token is *end-of-string* which is marked by regex as `$`. By adding the `x` as in the example provided above: `"ABC 2015 ABC1 x"` you *create* that "next character" and then you'll get a match between "ABC1 " to `\b\w+\D\b`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have now analyzed on the issue some more in detail, and I think it is clear now. Most of the confusion on the explanations actually came from that it was not obvious that which of your statements relate to which example string. According to your suggestion I will cast the vote to Avinash' answer myself, nevertheless I appreciate your help as well.